# WSO2 MI DECODE_MULTIPART_DATA isn't passed to endpont in blocking mode

Tags: wso2, multipartform-data, decode, blocking, wso2-micro-integrator

I'am sending multipart/form-data message using sequence like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="PostMessagesBlockingSequence">
    <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="multipart/form-data"/>
    <property name="DECODE_MULTIPART_DATA" value="true" scope="axis2" type="BOOLEAN"/>
    <call blocking="true">
        <endpoint key="PostMessagesEndpoint"/>
    </call>
    <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/json"/>
</sequence>
```

This sequence is called from custom mediator which is called as a handler from broker.

But DECODE_MULTIPART_DATA is not passed to endpoint which causing, that multipart data are not decoded from Base64.

Without blocking="true" I'm getting response from endpoint but in another thread.

I'am using WSO2 Micro Integrator 4.1.0

Thanks in advance

I tried a lot of things, but nothing worked

Comment: Why are you using the blocking mode?

Comment: @ycr For business purposes. It is mandatory to achieve synchronicity, when it will be for example 100 calls in one time.

Comment: Unless you are doing a message polling scenario (JMS Inbound Endpoints etc.) the synchronicity will work without blocking true.

Answer (score 0):

Call Mediator is synchronous by nature. Blocking mode is an implementation-level detail that is not typically useful for the end user. When you set blocking mode to true, the underline thread that handles the request is blocked and not returned to the thread pool. In non-blocking mode, the threads are returned, but in both modes, the integrations will not continue until you receive a response from the backend. So the integration will always be synchronous. The non-blocking mode can be problematic when you are working with message polling scenarios.
Having said that, you should always try to use non-blocking mode as that's the recommended approach due to the efficiency.

For the issue you are facing with the non-blocking mode try setting the following before the call mediator.

```xml
<property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING" value="true" scope="axis2" />
```

Comment: Unfortunately, after removing blocking="true" and add DISABLE_CHUNKING property i didn't get response from endpoint

Comment: @Fiko Can you enable wirelogs as described here https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/administer-and-observe/logs/configuring_log4j_properties/#wire-logs-and-header-logs
and do the request while blocking true and false and add the logs?

Comment: I can't really ;/. Logs are almost the same - headers etc. are the same. In blocking mode multipart data are in Base64

Comment: @Fiko Edit the original question and add the logs.

Comment: I meant I am not allowed to share those logs

Comment: @Fiko If there is no difference it should work :)

Comment: Without blocking true I see in logs that there is response but in antoher thread. In custom mediator there is same context as before called sequence

Comment: I'm not following you. Are you saying it's failing in a custom mediator you have?

Comment: yeah, basically. Sequence is called in custom mediator and I need to get response from that sequence in this custom mediator. I am afraid it's not possible in nonblocking mode...