# Inappropriate decoding Base64 PDF to String in Java

Tags: java, string, pdf, base64

I have encoded Base64 PDF file:

```
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
```

I am trying to decode this into String like this:
`new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(encoded.getBytes()))`

But after this the decoded pdf structure is different than the original which cause, that result is just a blank white paper nad it's size is bigger than original.

**Fragment of Original**:

```
%PDF-1.7
%ÇěŹ˘
5 0 obj
<</Length 6 0 R/Filter /FlateDecode>>
stream
xśMŠ±ƒ0Dw…ÇdŔµIlĂZ‰Ą[Á[Ő    ©ť2đ˙ĐŞRď-Ow·!“+ňÉOÖŚoŘ@¨śů”˙ľ6Ľ\fGaRĂx|OhF^« [OĺX<RLą«ÄjŁ¤%ŹÄ6¨§Č©—„ů7˜î;(˘ôendstream
endobj
```

**Fragment of Decoded**:

```
%PDF-1.7
%�쏢
5 0 obj
<</Length 6 0 R/Filter /FlateDecode>>
stream
x�M���0Dw��d��Il�Z��[�[�    ��2��ЪR�-Ow�!�+��O��o�@������6�\fGaR�x�|OhF^��[O�X<RL���j��%��6�������7��;(��endstream
endobj
```

I don't understand what is going on. I would be very grateful for tips.

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to print it on the screen. Write it on the disk directly and check the PDF. Not sure how you got that content with corrupt characters, but it could be due to encoding issues while showing the bytes.
Since you have Base64 encoded PDF string, you don't have to convert it to `byte[]` too.  Directly pass it to `decode()` method.

```
String pdfB64 = "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";
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("D:/Temp/test.pdf");
fos.write(Base64.getDecoder().decode(pdfB64));
fos.close();
```

I directly wrote the decoded bytes to the disk, and test.pdf opens up fine with 'TEST' as text on the one-page PDF.

Update...

```
String pdfB64 = "JVBERi0xL......JUVPRgo=";
byte[] pdfBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(pdfB64);
Charset ch = StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1;
String pdfStr = new String(pdfBytes, ch);
System.out.println(pdfStr);  // This still shows corrupt, but that is due to CLI limitation
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("D:/Temp/test.pdf");
fos.write(pdfStr.getBytes(ch));
fos.close();
```

Converting the `byte` array to string and back to the `byte` array using `ISO_8859_1` results in the same `byte` array in this sample case.
The file written on the disk is valid and opens up fine.
The only thing is both sides have to use the same charset for the conversion. So, the WSO2 side also has to have the option to use this charset to convert the received string to a `byte` array.

**BEST OPTION** would always be to pass Base64 encoded string and let the other side decode it and get the byte array, which can then be used as PDF content.

Comment: The problem is I don't need file on disk. I need to pass decoded PDF as String to context in WSO2 solution...

Comment: Fiko ... you can't pass an (unencoded) PDF as a String.   It is a BINARY format.  Which "WSO2 solution" are you referring to?   What is "going on" is that converting the PDF binary to a string is giving you garbage.

Comment: @StephenC https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76869867/wso2-mi-decode-multipart-data-isnt-passed-to-endpont-in-blocking-mode

Comment: Best option is to pass Base64 encoded string to the other side, and have the other side decode it and use it as byte[] directly, and not try to convert byte array to string.  I don't know about WSO2, but if you are passing the byte array - make sure you are using the bytes read from the InputStream as-is and use those bytes as they are.  If you try to convert it to a String, it may get corrupted.  Still, try to use 'UTF-8' encoding to convert byte[] to string. But whenever it is to be converted back to byte[] it has to use the same encoding.  Directly using Base64 string is the best option.

Comment: I take it back. Don't convert byte[] to string even using UTF-8 or UTF-16. Converting back that string to byte[] using the same charset also corrupts the byte array. I tried it.  So, either Base64 encoded string (other side has to decode and use byte[] as pdf content) OR the decoded bytes as-is (the other side has to accept byte stream and use it as is as pdf content)

Comment: One more try.  I used `ISO_8859_1` like this `String pdfStr = new String(pdfBytes, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1)`. And then again converted to byte array to string using the same charset, e.g. `pdfStr.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1)`. This results in the same byte array as the original decoded array. Wrote it to the file and the file opened fine.  So, if the WSO2 side has the option to specify the charset, try using this one.

Comment: Yeah, i got valid pdf too, but still it is byte[] insetad of String

Comment: The likelihood that you can get away with sending anything other than a known, fixed pdf file as a string is so low that it shouldn't even be attempted. An API that requires receiving this is wrong, *unless* it's base64 encoded